# Can I set one of 3 specific IP addresses as exit node? What is the syntax?

Tags: configuration

Ive been experimenting and looking for info on this. 
Want to rotate between 3 specific exit nodes located in one country. 
What is the syntax for Exitnodes parameter?

Answer (score 0):

hashes, not ip's are specified. You need to get their tor ID's and specify as it says "in comma-separated list"